# Как вызвать функцию JQuery при скроленге страницы?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Когда я прокручиваю страницу и когда на ней (в тексте) появляется блок, или определенное слово, то тогда должна выполнится функция:

```
<p ondragover='rush()' id='up'><a href='index.php'>fdfdfd</a></p>
```

Кто-то знает как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Плагин viewport-checker выполняет указанный код, когда блок при прокрутке появляется в видимой области монитора.

Answer (score 0):

может подойдет что-то в этом плане

```
        var per=0;

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if($(window).scrollTop()<per || per<100){
                $(".wrapper_up").removeClass("top-60");
                $(".menu").removeClass("top0");
            }
            else{
                $(".wrapper_up").addClass("top-60");
                $(".menu").addClass("top0");
            }
            per = $(window).scrollTop();
        })

    </script>
```

Comment: А можешь еще примерчик написать, вроде <p ondragover='rush()' id='up'><a href='index.php'>fdfdfd</a></p>

Comment: тоесть вам надо событие при перетаскивании элемента а не при скролинге страницы?

Comment: Событие нужно при скролинге страници. Когда я дохожу до нужного мне блока, должно сработать событие.

Comment: Мой скрипт приведенный начинает отрабатывать при расстоянии от верха страницы в 100 пикселей... Если расстояние постоянное можете захардкодить конкретное расстояние... А если нет то можно проверку ставить от расстояния от верха страницы до блока...